# How to swap/pass a value of an attribute as a value to another attribute?

Tags: javascript, custom-data-attribute

I have an attribute `data-ms-member = "secret"`

This value of secret loads only while loading the page. So, say, after the page load I will have the value of `data-ms-member = "98756849320764182"`

I want this value to be equal to another attribute name like say, `data-item-memberid = "98756849320764182"`

Anyone can help me to get some insights on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dataset` for this matter. Here's a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pLc03whz/).

```
const el = document.querySelector('[data-item-memberid]')
const id = el.dataset.itemMemberid;
const newEl = document.querySelector('[data-ms-member]');
newEl.dataset.msMember = id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var msMember = document.querySelectorAll('[data-ms-member]')[0];
var memberId = document.querySelectorAll('[data-item-memberid]')[0];

msMember.setAttribute("data-ms-member", memberId.getAttribute("data-item-memberid"));
```

Comment: Use `querySelector(selector)` rather than `querySelectorAll(selector)[0]`. Also, code without explanation is less likely to be upvoted than code which explains what was written and why.

Answer (score 0):

Use the setAttribute method to set attribute and its value!

```
var member= document.getElementById('data-ms-member');//id of data-ms-member field

var memberId = document.getElementById('data-item-memberid');//id of data-item-memberid field

memberId.setAttribute("data-item-memberid", member.getAttribute("data-ms-member"));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting; also, code without explanation is less likely to be upvoted than code which explains what was written and why.